# Why is Talend giving ClassNotFoundException for SQLServerDriver

Tags: talend

I've installed Talend ESB 6.5.1 and am trying to connect to a SQL Server database.

I tried using the JTDS driver, but that didn't work, and it appeared that I needed a DLL that wasn't included in the , and do I installed the pure java MS driver instead.

Talend has put the MS driver into `Studio\workspace\xxx\temp\dbWizard` having renamed it, but when I try to use it I get

```
Database connection is failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:195)
...
```

It looks like Talend has put the jdbc driver somewhere, but it not referencing it correctly.

Any ideas what I need to do to get Talend to find it? (I've looked inside the .jar file and the class is definitely there.)

(Taking the generated JDBC URL and using this directly in a tJDBCInput with the driver jar selected works fine... bizarre)

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  I am having the same problem.  I tried iMezouar's answer (removing all the jars from there to a temp folder then restarting Talend.  But it did not prompt about installing them again.  So I opened the modules view and installed each of those jars back again.  They appear again in the temp\dbwizard folder, and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The location where your jar was put does not look familiar. Try deleting all the jtds jar versions in the following locations :

```
<Talend root folder>\configuration\.m2\repository\org\talend\libraries
<Talend root folder>\lib\java
```

And restart your studio. When you go back to your component, you'll see an install button. You should be able to download and install the jar.